# Opening/closing divs

Tags: javascript

I've got a section on my site that has a few headings, each with content related to it in a section that drops down when you click on the heading. I've tried to add some javascript to it so that, when you click the heading the content appears, and all of the other content that's open disappears. It works for the first few open-close tests, but after a while, they stay open. I'm wondering if there's a way to make it so that you can only ever have one of those sections open.

Thanks in advance!

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="heading">Header 1</div>
<div class="headingcontent">Content 1</div>
<div class="heading">Header 2</div>
<div class="headingcontent">Content 2</div>
<div class="heading">Header 3</div>
<div class="headingcontent">Content 3</div>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery(".headingcontent").hide();
var headingcontent_open = false;

jQuery(".heading").click(function () {

    if (headingcontent_open === false) {
        headingcontent_open = true;
        jQuery(this).next(".headingcontent").slideToggle(500);

    } else {
        headingcontent_open = false;
        $(".headingcontent").hide(500);
        jQuery(this).next(".headingcontent").slideToggle(500);

    }

});
```

Comment: Hi. can you upload jsbin ? ( jsbin.com)

Comment: I've removed all the non-related sections of the site (I'm assuming none of them were interfering) http://jsbin.com/otigek/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give each content div a id and set a data-* attribute in the header tag and refer to it in the jQuery code while using a "active" class.

```
<div class="heading" data-content="content1">Header 1</div>
<div class="headingcontent" id="content1">Content 1</div>
<div class="heading" data-content="content2">Header 2</div>
<div class="headingcontent" id="content2">Content 2</div>
<div class="heading" data-content="content3">Header 3</div>
<div class="headingcontent" id="content3">Content 3</div>
```

javascript:

```
jQuery(".heading").click(function () {
     var ContentDivID = $(this).data("content");

     $(".headingcontent").removeClass("active");
     $("#"+ContentDivID).addClass("active").slideDown(500); //Slides down the active div
     $(".headingcontent").not(".active").slideUp(500); //Slides up all the content divs that dont have the "active" class
});
```

This assumes you are using HTML5 as data-* are html5 attributes, if you are targeting browsers that dont have those available you will have to modify the code to suit that situation.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer - I played around with it a little and it works! Much appreciated :)